# iOS: fill array with selected state of buttons from UITableViewCell's defined in another Class

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have an app which has a `UITableView`. The `UITableView` has it's custom `UITableViewCells` defined in another class, `CustomCell`. These cells are added to the `UITableView` by a button defined in the `UIViewController`. In the cells there is a `UIButton`, which are selected when the cells are created and they change selected state every time the button is pressed. I need an `NSMutableArray` to be created containing the selected state of the `UIButton` of each cell. The selected state of the button in the row n of the table view would be in index n of the `NSMutableArray`. I want to add 1 to the array if the button is selected and 0 if its not. I'm gonna use that array to refresh the data in the `UITableView` and to do some calculations later.

my problems:

-I don't know how to change the value of the array specific to the button I just pressed right when I press it, since the button is defined in another class.

-If I select a button at the n-th row, then every 8th row the button on those rows become selected, even if I still haven't created those cells yet, when I create them the button'll be selected. (e.g. if I click button on row 1, buttons on rows 9, 17, 25,... become selected/deselected as well)

-Only way I found to use the array was to create a new one every time I needed it, by iterating through each cell of the `UITableView`and adding 1s/0s if the button was selected/deselected. I'm sure there's a better way.

heres my code:

`CustomCell.h`

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *tickButton;
```

`CustomCell.m`

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)tick:(UIButton *)sender {

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        _isTicked = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    }
    else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        _isTicked = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    }

}
```

MainViewController.h

```
@interface SplitBillViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *addItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *itemTable;
```

MainViewController.m

```
@implementation MainViewController{
    BOOL lastButtonPressed;
    NSInteger n;
    NSNumber *a;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section==0) return n;
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier= @"Cell";

        CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }


        if ([indexPath row]%2==0){
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:0.8]];
        }
        else{
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.94 green:0.94 blue:0.94 alpha:0.9]];
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.accessoryView = [UIView new];
        return cell;
    }

    }

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        lastButtonPressed=NO;
        --n;
        [_itemTable reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)addItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    lastButtonPressed=YES;
    ++n;
    [_itemTable reloadData];
    [_itemTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:n-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    [_itemTable endEditing:YES];
}

-(NSMutableArray*) returnTickArray{
    NSMutableArray *tickArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:n];
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<n; i++){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [self.itemTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       // NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cell.isTicked]);
        if ([cell.tickButton isSelected]){
            a=[NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        }
        else {
            a=[NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        };
        [tickArray addObject:a];
    }
    return tickArray;
}

@end
```

There is, of course, more code, but I didn't copy anything I was sure doesn't affect anything.

thanks!

Comment: For your problems you can try delegate method : http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try like this ,

1.take one `NSMutableArray` for selelcted buttons.

2.when you selecte particuler button at that time add that `indexpath.row` value to the array.

3.when you delselect the button at that time check wheateher that indexpath.row value present in that array or not ,if yes then find the index of that object and remove that object from the array.

```
if([array containsObject:@"value"]){
        int n=[array indexOfObject:@"value"];
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:n];

    }
```

when yiu click on button this method will call ,in this method you can manage all the thins,

```
- (IBAction)tick:(UIButton *)sender {

//here you will get tag value like sender.tag value.

if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        _isTicked = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

       NSString *value=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sender.tag];
       if([array containsObject:value]){
          int n=[array indexOfObject:value];
          [array removeObjectAtIndex:n];

       }
    }
    else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        _isTicked = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sender.tag]];//if already present in array the skip this one
    }
}
```

otherwise you'l get indexPath value directly by using like this.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [yourtableviewname indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview];
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
```

Comment: I don't know how I add the indexpath.row value to the array. Since the button is defined in CustomCell, the only way I know so far that I can make it perform an action is through the addTarget:actions:forControlEvents, which doesn't take arguments. If it took arguments I could send the indexPath as argument

Comment: k fine for this take one tag value for the button replace the indexpath.row value by that button tag value and tag value must be same as indexpath.row value.

Comment: but how do I use the tag value when button is pressed then? ty for being patient, I'm fairly new to all of this

Comment: I didn't know what was a tag value til you mentioned it btw :p

Answer (score 0):

> -If I select a button at the n-th row, then every 8th row the button on those rows become selected, even if I still haven't created those cells yet, when I create them the button'll be selected. (e.g. if I click button on row 1, buttons on rows 9, 17, 25,... become selected/deselected as well)

That is because the cells are reused. You need to worry about this at the level of your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. For *every* cell here, meaning *every* time this method is called, you need to specify whether the button is to be selected or not.

Comment: that's one of the reasons I need to build the array. Every other element on the cell (which are not showing) "have"a array and are not repeating every 8th row. Btw, why 8? It seems pretty random :p

Comment: Just use NSMutableIndexSet to keep track.

Comment: "Just use NSMutableIndexSet to keep track." Yes, or even better, plan ahead: add a BOOL to your actual model, so you can indicate whether the button there is selected or not. That way you just have *one* model object containing *everything* we need to know about *every* cell.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the following steps
  You need an array to keep track of the selected buttons. Iam going to save the indexPath of the corresponding buttons in that array. Create an array as property

```
   @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray* selectedIndexPaths;

   // In viewDidLoad  
   self.selectedIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

1. In **cellForRowAtIndexPath**
   Add the buttons programmatically. No need to add it in custom cell class

   ```
   if (cell == nil)
   {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
   cell.textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   [button setTitle:@"Press Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   button.frame = CGRectMake(200, 10, 100,30);
   button.tag = indexPath.row;
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [cell addSubview:button];
   [cell bringSubviewToFront:button];
   }
   ```
2. **When you press button**
    Add/Remove the indexPath of button in selectedIndexPath array

   ```
   -(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
   {
   NSLog(@"Button Pressed");

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)sender.superview];
   if([self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
      [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];

    }
   else
   {
    [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
   }
   NSLog(@"SelectedIndexPaths : %d",self.selectedIndexPaths.count);
   }
   ```
3. Now you have indexPath of all the selected button cells. Do whatever you want